# What is the best way to query a list in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I want to know **What is the best way to query a list in sharepoint 2013**

- CAML
- Linq
- Server Object Model

Cannot use client object model.  I am looking for a cleaner way as there will only be less then 30 items in each list or document library.

Comment: http://blog.furuknap.net/why-linq-to-sharepoint-is-a-bad-idea <-- I never use Linq to SP. SharePoint is dynamic. Linq to SP is not. In the article he gets into this in "The Ugly" around "Well, LINQ to SharePoint won’t pick up on such changes. In fact, as I’ll explain in a moment, LINQ to SharePoint is highly static and works only for a definition of the data model that was current at the time of the start of development."

Comment: +1, you are right, i just figured this out.

Comment: but if we write it on required columns, like ids and names, it should be fine

Comment: I think the problem with your question is that there is no one best way. It all depends on what you're doing, and where you're trying to do it.

Comment: i agreeeeeeeeeee

Comment: I agree with @RJCuthbertson that the question is too broad. Without further context, I would argue that the best way to query a 30 item list is to use the SharePoint user interface and create a view - no code needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot do that by **Client Object Model** you can do only with Server Object Model.

Depends on you knowledge you can be conformable with one instead of other.

For example this is a rest query:

```
http://lsspf4719/sites/TestWebs/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Employees(2)
```

> Returns the specified list item by ID (2) as an Atom feed with one
>   entry that corresponds to the requested item.

Instead with Server Object Model you can do a C# code like that:

```
 using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite(pathToSite)) {  
    using(SPWeb oWeb = oSite.AllWebs[nameOfWeb]) {   
      // Alternately you can use oSite.RootWeb if you want to access the main site  

      SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[listName];

      foreach(SPListItem oItem in oList.Items) {  
        // Access each item in the list...  
        // etc....  
      }  

    }  
  }
```

Then using CAML on your query can make the data that come back lightweight.
If you want use LINQ then you need to use SPMetal to create your Context.
Take a look on this link to understand how: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ocarpen/archive/2010/12/23/good-practices-with-linq-to-sharepoint.aspx?Redirected=true

Personally, if I cannot write any COM code, I prefer use LINQ but it has some limits.